# Accessing Active Directory from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, active-directory

I want to access Active Directory and to be able to execute LDAP queries via stored procedure in SQL Server.

How do I declare a linked server for that?

How do I declare LDAP queries?

Thanks in advance

Kobi

Comment: **Don't** - it's technology that's been [deprecated and removed from SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707782.aspx) - don't use it, it's not a good choice. Use some other way to get the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://sql.dzone.com/news/querying-active-directory-thro